# How can I make fit the diagram in the page?

Tags: dia

I know that I can make [Dia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dia_%28software%29) to fit a diagram into a page of a fixed size:

[image]

But I want the resulting / exported pdf-page to have no border. Currently, I use [pdfcrop](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/) for this task, but I would like to do it with Dia. The export **must** be to a PDF with vector graphics.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: What does "have no border" mean?

Comment: When you look at the image, you can see that there is some space below of the diagram on the page. I want the page to end at the end of the diagram. So I should perhaps call it "padding" instead of border?

Comment: So what you want is to set the image to stretch across the whole page, such that there is no extra room on the page?

Comment: No. I want the page to have the aspect ratio that my diagram has, not vice versa.

Comment: I just tried to do what you're asking for using Dia on Linux Mint, and it works. I set all margins to 0cm in Page Setup, then I exported to PDF with the *fit to 1 by 1* option enabled. Output is an A4 PDF with no borders and the aspect ratio is correct.

Comment: BTW it seems what @moose was asking for is impossible. Say you want A4 output. Unless the diagram proportions have an aspect ratio equivalent to A4, there *will* be white space either top/bottom or left/right because any kind of stretching to fill all space would distort the aspect ratio.

Comment: @misha256 You didn't understand my question. I don't want A4 output (nor letter or any other pre-defined format). I want an PDF output which has the same aspect ratio as my drawing.

Comment: @moose Gotcha, sorry for my misunderstanding. What OS are you running, Windows Linux Mac?

Comment: @misha256 Doesn't matter. I know how to fix the problem, but I want to know how to do it directly with `dia`.

Comment: @moose Ok that makes things really simple actually, *you can't do it directly through dia*. Being open source software someone could implement the feature though.

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible to do this natively in Dia.

Being open source software, the feature could be implemented.

There is nothing that technically prevents a PDF from having custom dimensions (but it can't have *no* dimensions, that goes without saying I think).

Just in case Dia coders are reading this, the way I see the feature implemented would look like this:

1. You would still have to select a paper size in Page Setup.
2. You would set all margins to zero
3. You would then tick a check-box named something like "Crop paper size to fit content"

On export, Dia would first scale the image to best fit the paper size, then adjust the paper size in one dimension to eliminate remaining empty space, then perform the render to PDF.

Who wants to implement this? If I had the coding expertise I would, because frankly this would be an excellent feature which I'd use myself too.

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to do it in Dia natively. But it can be done in two simple steps:

1. Export the diagram to EPS (Encapsulated PostScript (using Pango fonts)) to get borderless vector graphics
2. Convert EPS to PDF: `epstopdf mydiagram.eps`

[epstopdf](https://ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf) is part of most TeX distributions.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is (in Linux anyway) is to use Page Setup to fit the page to 1 x 1, then Print -> Print to file, and print it as PDF.  The resulting PDF will be a single page document.

Comment: The resulting PDF will still have the aspect ratio of the page set up in the printer driver and not the aspect ratio of the diagram as the OP wants it.

Answer (score 0):

To get an image without any padding, you can export the image as a .png:

[image]

If you want to print the image as it appears in Dia, go to Page Setup and set the scale to 100 and the margins to whatever you like (It's not clear if you wanted to set them to 0 or not.) Make sure that the image falls within the blue lines, as that is your page outline.

[image]

Comment: This way it will only have one of the sizes / aspect ratios provided in "Paper size". So this is not a solution to my problem.

Comment: Making a custom page size in a PDF is a pretty non-standard thing to do, so I don't think you are going to have much luck getting it done in one step.

Comment: I know it's a non-standard thing to do, but the point it if I save in PNG, it's not vector graphic anymore. Later on if I want to embed it in a pdf built from latex, a pdf image would be the best, and that's why I prefer the pdf file with no ANY extra padding.

Answer (score -2):

1 export file as SVG.
2 open SVG in Inkscape and save copy as PDF.

Answer (score -2):

In *File -> Page Setup -> Scaling* select the **Fit to** radio button option and set it to 1 by 1 (it's the default option in my installation) and that fits the diagram to the page.

That worked perfectly for me. Hope that helps

Best regards.

Comment: This does not work. It still leaves a border. And as you can see in the screenshot of the question, this was already described as the way which does **not** work.

Comment: @MartinThoma Sorry, I didn't read well the question. I've just tried setting the margins to zero and printing with any PDF printer. Am I understanding correctly your problem? Tell me and I'll edit the answer